# Application of the reverse Fatou's lemma for limits in the continuum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let  $(f_{\delta})_{\delta \in [0,1)}$ be functions with $f_\delta : \mathbb{N} \mapsto [0, \infty)$,
such that there exists $g$ satisfying $f_\delta \leq g$ for any $\delta \in [0,1)$ and  $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} g(n) < \infty$.
Does the following inequality hold?
$$
\limsup_{ \delta \rightarrow 0} \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_{\delta}(n) \leq 
\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \limsup_{ \delta \rightarrow 0}  f_{ \delta}(n).
$$
I would like to use the reverse Fatou's lemma to justify it, my problem is that the limit $\delta \rightarrow 0$ is not a sequence of integer values.  Is in this case the inequality still justified?

Comment: Reverse Fatou's Lemma (given functions $f_n$) also needs the functions to be dominated by another function $g$, because you need $g-f_n$ to be nonnegative to prove it

Comment: Thanks. I added this condition in the assumption. But given this, does the inequality holds?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm I'm pretty sure it does hold. Either inspect the proof of reverse Fatou, or try to use the fact that $g(\delta) \to L$ as $\delta \to 0$ iff $g(\delta_n) \to L$ for all sequences $\delta_n \to 0$.

Comment: thanks, sorry for the stupid question, how can I justify that $g(\delta) \rightarrow L$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0$ iff  $g(\delta_n) \rightarrow L$ for all sequences $\delta_n \rightarrow 0$?